# How to use JavaScript object as filter criteria?

Tags: javascript

I have an object that stores details for relationships between items that looks like this:

```
var allLinks = [
  {
    source: { itemname: "Hello World", index: 0 },
    target: { itemname: "Do Stuff", index: 1 }
  },
  {
    source: { itemname: "Do Stuff", index: 1 },
    target: { itemname: "Hello World", index: 0 }
  },
  {
    source: { itemname: "Do Things", index: 2 },
    target: { itemname: "Hello World", index: 0 }
  },
  {
    source: { itemname: "Hello World", index: 0 },
    target: { itemname: "Do Things", index: 2 }
  }
];
```

What I'm trying to do is develop a function that removes all of the relationships from the object where an item that is being removed/deleted is involved in (either as `source` or `target`). I created a function that collects the relationships that need to be removed in an array (`node` represents the item being removed/deleted):

```
    let linksToRemove = [];
    allLinks.map((item) => {
      if (item.source.index === node.index) {
        linksToRemove.push(item);
      }
      if (item.target.index === node.index) {
        linksToRemove.push(item);
      }
    });
```

This produces an output like:

```
var linksToRemove = [
  {
    source: { itemname: "Hello World", index: 0 },
    target: { itemname: "Do Stuff", index: 1 }
  },
  {
    source: { itemname: "Do Stuff", index: 1 },
    target: { itemname: "Hello World", index: 0 }
  }
];
```

So I'm trying to use that output to filter the `allLinks` object like this:

```
linksToRemove.map((li) => {
  allLinks.filter((item) => item.index !== li.index);
})
```

The problem is that this method appears to be removing the relationship content, but maintaining items indexed with `undefined` content. Am I missing something with how `filter` works or is there another explanation for what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Filter doesn't mutate the array it creates a new one. You need to reassign. `as = as.filter(f);`

Comment: Also, `allLinks.filter((item) => item.index !== li.index);` doesn't make much sense> the `item` or `li` is an object that does not have the key `index`. It contains only `source` and `target` objects, which in turn contains the `index` key. Can you show us what your `node` looks like? I have a feeling this can be easily done in a single pass.

Comment: @AluanHaddad That fixed it...simpler than I thought!

Comment: That's often how I feel. By the way if you don't return anything from a map call back you should use forEach instead of map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you may find is that you don't need `linksToRemove` and you don't need to alter `allLinks`.  All you may need is `filter`.

*Note: if you want `allLinks` to be updated as part of the function call, you can slap `allLinks =` in front of the `allLinks.filter(...)`.*

```js
let allLinks = getData();

function remove(node) {

  return allLinks.filter(item => ![
      item.source.index, 
      item.target.index
    ].includes(node.index) )
}

console.log(remove({index: 1}))



/********************************************************/
function getData() {
  return [{
      source: {
        itemname: "Hello World",
        index: 0
      },
      target: {
        itemname: "Do Stuff",
        index: 1
      }
    },
    {
      source: {
        itemname: "Do Stuff",
        index: 1
      },
      target: {
        itemname: "Hello World",
        index: 0
      }
    },
    {
      source: {
        itemname: "Do Things",
        index: 2
      },
      target: {
        itemname: "Hello World",
        index: 0
      }
    },
    {
      source: {
        itemname: "Hello World",
        index: 0
      },
      target: {
        itemname: "Do Things",
        index: 2
      }
    }
  ];
}
```

Comment: This is great, I didn't think to use `.includes` like that before. For others that might see this, I'm using `react` with the `useState` hook, so to update `allLinks` as part of the function call, I'm just putting the `allLinks.filter(...)` inside of my `setState` function.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question based on @AluanHaddad comment on the original post for visibility. I needed to reassign the `allLinks` array since `filter` doesn't mutate it (it creates a new one).

```
linksToRemove.forEach(li => {
  allLinks = allLinks.filter(item => item.index !== li.index);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var allLinks = [{
    source: {
      itemname: "Hello World",
      index: 0
    },
    target: {
      itemname: "Do Stuff",
      index: 1
    }
  },
  {
    source: {
      itemname: "Do Stuff",
      index: 1
    },
    target: {
      itemname: "Hello World",
      index: 0
    }
  },
  {
    source: {
      itemname: "Do Things",
      index: 2
    },
    target: {
      itemname: "Hello World",
      index: 0
    }
  },
  {
    source: {
      itemname: "Hello World",
      index: 0
    },
    target: {
      itemname: "Do Things",
      index: 2
    }
  }
];


var linksToRemove = [{
    source: {
      itemname: "Hello World",
      index: 0
    },
    target: {
      itemname: "Do Stuff",
      index: 1
    }
  },
  {
    source: {
      itemname: "Do Stuff",
      index: 1
    },
    target: {
      itemname: "Hello World",
      index: 0
    }
  }
];

const result = allLinks.filter(x => !linksToRemove.some(y =>
  y.source.index === x.source.index && y.target.index === x.target.index))
  
console.log('result', result)
```